# actionscript: embed glyphs by code

Tags: apache-flex, flash, actionscript-3, actionscript, fonts

you can embed certain glyphs of a font via the Flash IDE.

is this also possible by code only? (without the IDE)

```
[Embed(source='Fonts/arial.swf'
,fontName='Arial' )]
public static var font:Class;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible, see [Using embedded fonts](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=fonts_04.html) (look for 'unicodeRange').

Comment: thanks, but when i use unicodeRange i get this error: Error: transcoding parameter 'unicodeRange' is not supported by 'flex2.compiler.media.MovieTranscoder'. i am using flexsdk3.5 do i need to upgrade to 4?

Comment: It's for embedding font files, not swf (also needs mimeType="application/x-font").

Comment: It might possibly have something to do with which version of Flex you are using.

Answer (score 4):

There is a difference in embedding with the Flex SDK you are using (embedAsCFF propertie).

**Flex 4.x SDK**

```
[Embed(source="../lib/CustomFont.ttf", embedAsCFF="false", fontName="CustomFont", mimeType="application/x-font")]
public var CustomFont:Class;
```

**Flex 3.x SDK**

```
[Embed(source="../lib/CustomFont.ttf", fontName="CustomFont", mimeType="application/x-font")]
public var CustomFont:Class;
```

Note1: Don't forget to set textfield.embedFonts = true

Note2: You cannot use a swf as font, it should be an *.TTF or .OTF* file format

reference source: http://www.bit-101.com/blog/?p=2555

Comment: small addition: there is also .PFB format (Printer Font Binary,) by Adobe.

Answer (score 2):

For Flex3 you can also try Antialiaser: a free AIR application that makes OpenType and TrueType font visualization easy, allowing you to embed certain glyphs and customize all font setting, so you can use them later inside your Flex and AIR projects.

http://www.cycle-it.com/antialiaser/